# C# generate image (png, jpeg) of x width and x height with random background color and 2 letters within it

Tags: c#

I would like to generate specific size images (png, jpeg) with random color background except white or really light colors (close to white) and inside the image should be 2 characters, first letter from `FirstName` and first letter from `LastName`.

Something like TFS online does.

How can I acheive that in C# (generating the random background color) ?

Example:

If your name is `Tony Vetrano` the image should look like this:

[image]

Here is the code I use, I have been using this one to generate captcha in ASP.NET

```
    public Image GetImage()
    {
        int height = 32;
        int width = 32;

        var randomText = "TV";

        var rnd = new Random();
        var fonts = new[] { "Verdana" };
        float orientationAngle = rnd.Next(0, 359);

        var index0 = rnd.Next(0, fonts.Length);
        var familyName = fonts[index0];


        using (var bmpOut = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);

            SizeF size = g.MeasureString(randomText, new Font(familyName, 12));

            int x = Convert.ToInt32((width / 2) - (size.Width / 2));
            int y = Convert.ToInt32((height / 2) - (size.Height / 2));


            LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), FromHtml("#FFFFFF"), FromHtml("#FFFFFF"), orientationAngle);
            g.FillRectangle(gradientBrush, 0, 0, width, height);
            g.DrawString(randomText, new Font(familyName, 12), new SolidBrush(FromHtml("#169FE6")), x, y);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmpOut.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
            bmpOut.Dispose();
            ms.Close();


            using (MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream(bmpBytes))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(fileStream);
            }

        }
    }
    public static Color FromHtml(string colorHTML)
    {
        Color result = Color.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(colorHTML))
        {
            result = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colorHTML);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Just a second and I will post what I've done so far ...

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: I have no idea how to generate random background color with a color which is not white or closer to white. The text should always be white.

Comment: use `RGB` to pick random values between `0` and `200` instead of `255` (since you don't want light colors) and use it as background for your image.

Comment: @Enumy: do you mean Color.FromArgb(), and have a random number between 0 and 200 and the result will be Color.FromArgb(0, randomNumber, 0)?

Comment: Yes, that'll do it. set A=255, set the r&G to random <200 and make b dependent on them to keep a constant brightness.

Comment: yes you can make a function returns a random `int` between `0` and `200`.

Comment: Did it already: Random rand = new Random(); int randomR = rand.Next(0, 200); int randomG = rand.Next(0, 200); In fact the Random rand is declared as global variable. Perfect!

Comment: Appreciated your help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns an `Int32` between `minimum` and `maximum`.

```
public Int32 GetRandomNumber(Int32 minimum, Int32 maximum)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
    }
```

Then apply it to the `RGB` background